# View animation troubles

Tags: android, animation, position

The situation: I have a button (A) on the bottom of the screen and a bigger one (B) over it. Both children of the relative layout.

I want to show A button when user clicks button B, but not simply show - i want it to move from its position to the left by 50-100 dp.

I already done this, but there is a problem: the visual representation of A button is being moved succesfully, which I cannot say about its non-visual part. So when I click A - it does nothing. But if, than, I click on the place where it was - the onClick event is fired.

I realised, that its a common behavior of android animations and now I'm searching the way to set the non-visual button parts' position.

How can I do this?

Comment: ARe you using the fillAfter on your animation? It only changes the visual position of view. The view itself will remain in the same place as before. You should use an AnimationEndListener and move your Button to correct position in OnAnimationEnd.

Comment: I know about AnimationListener, and I want to use its onAnimationEnd, but the main thing is - how to set views' position? By now I didnt understand how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

OnAnimationEnd : try this :

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
```

(or wherever you want to move your View) 
then use

```
yourButton.setLayoutParams(params);
```